# Implication $\implies$ and iff $\iff$ operators

Tags: logic

Could you help me read (interpret) the truth tables of the two operators?

For the implication operator, the truth table is:

$$\begin{array}{c c | c}
 h& c&  h \implies c \\
 \hline
 T& T& T& \\
 T& F& F& \\
 F& T& T& \\
 F& F& T& \\
\end{array}$$

Is the third column indicating when the operator holds, in other words, when a value of $s$ CAN imply a value in $t$?

For the *"if and only if"* conditional connective, the truth table is:

$$\begin{array}{c c | c}
s& t& s \iff t \\
\hline
T&  T&  T& \\
T&  F&  F& \\
F&  T&  F& \\
F&  F&  T& \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, $p \implies q$ means "(not $p$) *or* $q$."
Thus if $p$ is false then not $p$ is true, so "(not $p$) *or* $q$" is also true.

Informally, $p \implies q$  means that *if* you know $p$ is *true* then you can conclude that $q$ is true. So if $p$ is false, then $p \implies q$ does not say anything about $q$. So the implication is always true. 
Whatever one wants is implied by a false statement.

Comment: Thank you for the great examples! Is the truth table saying that there are three ways in which you can prove $q$  from $p$?

Comment: You are welcome. No it does not say this. It just *explains* what it *means* that "$p \implies q$." You can derive $q$ from $p$ only if you know that $p \implies q$ is true and you know that $p$ is true.

Comment: OK, if I've understood well, then the last two lines together (of the truth table) are equivalent to your last sentence, namely: _"Whatever one wants is implied by a false statement."_

Comment: Yes, this a way to paraphrase it.

Answer (score 2):

The third column is showing you when the implication is false, an example is $$p \implies q$$
If p is true and q is false, the implication is false. "since truths cannot reach lies".

 The "if and only if"(iff) is a doble implication, $p \iff q$ is equivalent to say $p \implies q \land q \implies p$